# Unable to set focus to the map from a dockable window

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcobjects

I have a dockable window with a single listview control on it.  Selecting an item in the view will build a layer and add it to the map.  At the point of the layer being added to the map, I need to set focus to the map.  However, focus remains on the listview.

My issue is exactly the same as the following thread:  [How to set focus on ArcMap map window using arcobjects and c#.net](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/57748/how-to-set-focus-on-arcmap-map-window-using-arcobjects-and-c-net). I have followed the suggested answer in that thread of using an IntPtr, but it doesn't set focus to the map.

The following is the line of code that I am using in a public method after the layer has been added to the TOC and map:

```
SetFocus((IntPtr)ArcMap.Document.ActiveView.ScreenDisplay.hWnd);
```

As an fyi, I have also declared the following at the top of the class:

```
// Sets the keyboard focus to the specified window.
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto, ExactSpelling = true)]
public static extern IntPtr SetFocus(IntPtr hWnd);
```